# How to test iOS app on supporting IPv6? Apple rejected app as it is not IPv6 compatible

Tags: ios, ipv6, appstore-approval, ipv4, network-connection

have apps, built 2015 and 2014. How can I test them for IPv6?
If my apps doesn't support IPv6, what should I do?

My apps are using AFNetworking and Alamofire. I'm connecting mostly to domains ( Ex. api.example.com/v1/...). Only 1 app use IP: (ex: 12.12.12.12:3000/api/v1/...).
[image]

Comment: hi, do yo change your api server from ipV4 to ipV6 as well? Means its server end issue of we have to fix it at coding end?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38046187/how-to-fix-please-ensure-that-your-app-supports-ipv6-networks-as-ipv6-compatibi/38046471#38046471

Comment: @iphonemaclover: You don't have to change anything on the server side

Comment: then what i have to do?

Answer (score 18):

This solution only works if you have an **ethernet** connection.

For creating an **iPV6 NAT64** wifi network, follow these steps

**Step 1 :** Open system preferences

**Step 2 :** Open Sharing

**Step 3 :** Click on internet sharing

**Step 4 :** Click Wifi in the ports while pressing **option(ALT)** key. A **Create NAT64 Network** checkbox will be displayed on the bottom after that. It is important to press **ALT** while selecting WIFI for displaying the checkbox

[image]

**Step 5 :** check **Create NAT64 Network** checkbox.

Now test the application in the created network.

Answer (score 6):

The following [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1) from Apple outlines the requirements for transition to IPv6 support so I suggest reading it carefully. Apple provides guidelines to insure that your app is IPv6 compatible including which API's should and should not be used, not hard-coding IP addresses, etc. They even detail how to setup a local Mac-based IPv6 **DNS64/NAT64** network to test against.

Answer (score 3):

Holding **command + option** while clicking on the Sharing preference pane will add a "Create NAT64 Network" option for Internet Sharing. Enable that and devices connected through your shared connection will be in a **NAT64** connection.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this walkthrough in how to setup your Mac for Internet Sharing to test IPv6 from Brian Coleman to be quite helpful.

http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/

It has several screenshots, step-by-step instructions to guide you through the process.  I hope this helps!