# IOS Rejection the activity indicator spun indefinitely on launch, then no further action was generated at the time of review

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, app-store, wifi

Recently I submitted my App to App Store for review and get a rejection which says my App is loading forever:

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone and
>   iPad running iOS 12 on Wi-Fi.
>
> Specifically, the activity indicator spun indefinitely on launch, then
>   no further action was generated at the time of review.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please run your app on a device to identify any
>   issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review.
>
> If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to
>   this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these
>   features were intended to work.
>
> For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a
>   device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue. For
>   updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version,
>   then follow the steps to reproduce the issue.
>
> Resources
>
> For information about testing your app and preparing it for review,
>   please see Technical Note TN2431: App Testing Guide.
>
> For a networking overview, please review About Networking. For a more
>   specific overview of App Review’s IPv6 requirements, please review the
>   IPv6 and App Review discussion on the Apple Developer Forum.
>
> Please see attached screenshot for details.

Before I submit for review, I have tested it on simulators and real devices, both takes 5-10 seconds to open.

I am using Firebase and Ionic, can someone give me some suggestions, what caused this issue? I google searched that Firebase supports IPv6 and now I have no clue why the issue occurred.

There's no hardcoded IP in the source, the only URL I am using is querying rates from Canada Post by `url: 'https://ct.soa-gw.canadapost.ca/rs/ship/price'`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you properly handle bad or really slow network connections? No network connections?

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for your comment, the issue is it get stuck on the splash page when app store team review it, I’ve never had this before

Comment: But that's the point of my comment. You are only testing with a perfectly good and fast network connection. Try your app with a bad network connection. Make your app deal with such a case in a user friendly manner.

Comment: @rmaddy no the issue is stuck on splash screen forever, it's not related to the network quality. When I test it without network it goes to home page

Comment: You need to test with a poor network. One that is connected but very very slow in responding. There's a huge difference between handling no network and handling a really slow or non-responsive network.

Comment: I have tried poor network and IPv6(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969860/how-to-test-ios-app-on-supporting-ipv6), my app works in both cases...it can load in 5-10 seconds then goes to home page

Answer (score 2):

We are having the same kind of report from Apple despite the fact we are testing on 6 different devices, iOS 11, 12, 12.1 with or without network.

We are also getting no issues from our beta testers.

As far as I can tell, on the Launchscreen we are spending about 6 seconds (iPhoneX) waiting for Metal to launch. There is nothing else in our log until our first VC hits its viewDidLoad.

We had the same kind of report two weeks ago with a very different iteration of our app, on resubmission the app went through

Now we have tightened up a lot of app behaviour and been rejected for the same reason multiple times

Its frustrating because of the lack of supporting information from Apple, such as logs.